# Including resources in separate "resource" folder

Tags: java, eclipse

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere. I've gone through quite a few other questions but haven't yet worked out the answer.

I am trying to draw an image to a JPanel but I can't work out the path structure. I have the default "src" folder containing my packages. I have also created a "resources" folder at the same level as the src one. In this I have put the image I want to load. Can someone please help me with how to load images from this resources folder into a class in the src folder? My current code is as below:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/clach.jpg"));
image = ii.getImage();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the folder "resources" into the application's class path. Then you can just get the resource with

```
getClass().getResource("/resource-file")
```

If you are using Eclipse (which has the default src folder as a source folder), you can just right-click the resources folder and make a source folder of it under Build Path / Use as source folder.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
this.getClass().getResource("clach.jpg")
```

and make sure that you put resources folder on classpath.
Project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Add Folder

Comment: this would assume that clach.jpg is in the same package as the current class

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. You must make sure that the "resources" folder is copied to the classpath (e.g. it is present in `/bin` or in the target .jar)